# Submit button not changing/navigating page after clicked

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am working on writing automated tests with Selenium for a single page web application written in React-Admin.  I have a simple page where 4 fields are filled in, then a Submit button is clicked to save changes.  This results in the item created showing up in a table displayed on the page.

The issue is, when the Selenium script gets to the portion of clicking the Submit button, the save does actually happen, but the page does not change to show the table with the new entry.  It stays on the Edit screen where the information for this item was entered/having the Submit button at the bottom.

If I comment out the @AfterTest which closes the browser, I can see the pop-up occur that says, "Item Added - UNDO" which is just a snack bar style pop-up that gives the user the option to undo the change before final commit.  I can even navigate back a few times and see the new items exist - so it did definitely save the new item.

On the Selenium side, I've done the following.

- Put a simple Thread.sleep(3000) just before the submit.click();
- Put a WebDriverWait conditional wait looking for the button element
  to be visible

In either case, the page still doesn't go away after the Submit button is clicked.

If I simply duplicate the line of code that clicks the button, the 2nd one seems to make the page go away as expected.

This all seems very odd and inconsistent to me.  I have not had a fantastic time with trying to understand all of the when/why/hows behind the different waits available within Selenium - bit of a struggle.

If anyone has any ideas as to why the page does not go away when the button is clicked, yet the actual action is still performed, I would love to hear your thoughts.

I find myself feeling like I have to make my code very ... 'not elegant?' when trying to get Selenium to do what I'd like it to do.  Possibly this is due to this being a React-Admin site and having next to nothing to work with when interacting with elements in the DOM, or more likely, my lack of experience.

Any direction would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!
Bob

Comment: Please provide your code snippet

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be a bug in the code and the test caught it.

Good game, Selenium.